# xml DatePicker in Dialog contentView not working

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker

I'm new to Android, and I'm building an app in which I've got an xml DatePicker in a Dialog's contentView. For the dialog's button to display the slected date, I have the following code:

```
                // get Date Button 
    Button dialogGetVButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.GetVerseB);  
    dialogGetVButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        int day = pickerC.getDayOfMonth(); 
        int month = pickerC.getMonth(); 
        showEtext.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1) 
                   .append("-").append(day).append("-").append("2012")); 
        dialog.dismiss(); 
    } 
    }); 
    // END get Date Button
```

it looks like `getDayOfMonth(); and getMonth();` are not the correct calls to the DatePicker because clicking the button crashes the app. All I want it to do is display the selected DatePicker date in the showEtext TextView. Is anyone out there doing a custom DatePicker along these lines? And if so, what would be the correct code to accomplish this? I know the above code works when the xml DatePicker is on it's own, not being called in a Dialog's contentView. But this code doesn't work when in a Dialog.

Comment: Please post your logcat errors.

Comment: I think the relevant logcat error is java.lang.NullPointerException. Which means the Dialog doesn't see the DatePicker, right? I've called `pickerC = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.picker_c);` in the Dialog code but still getting the nullexception error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I thought that

```
    int day = pickerC.getDayOfMonth();  
int month = pickerC.getMonth()
```

were incorrect calls - turns out they ARE correct. My problem was in not calling the DatePicker within the Dialog correctly. Originally I was doing: `pickerC = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.picker_c);` which I think, is just pulling the DatePicker into the main activity. I found that if I called: `pickerC = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.picker_c);` slapping dialog. in front of findViewById is the fix. That pulls the DatePicker into the Dialog so that the Dialog can "see" the DatePicker.